# Cannot use Advanced Digitizing Toolbar (greyed out)

Tags: qgis, toolbar

I am new to QGIS. I have one picture with the attribute table I created and the greyed out toolbar. Yes, I have it in "Toggle editing" but doesn't seem to make a difference....even after I close out of the attribute table. Am I missing something?

The shapefile (trap_location) is for points, and agri_landscape is for polygons.

[image]

Comment: Your table does not have geometries. Is it a CSV?

Comment: @MrXsquared The guide I have only specifies to build the Grid_code and farm columns, setting them as integer and text, respectively. The table is set as a starting point before starting polygons. If I add rows of information I still cannot edit....

Comment: Yes, because it isnt a geometry table. You can only edit or add geometries to a geometry-table. Do you want to create new geometry informations or edit existing ones?

Comment: @MrXsquared Create new.

Comment: You can click on "New Shapefile layer" or "New Geopackage layer" for example. Make sure to set the correct geometry-type and add the columns you want it to have.

Comment: @MrXsquared Thank you, just tried it and yes the new layers work. Glad it was a simple fix!

Answer (score 3):

You can not use advanced digitizing bar here because your layer isnt a geometry layer. To create a new layer with geometries you can click on "New Shapefile layer" or "New Geopackage layer" for example. Make sure to set the correct geometry-type and add the columns you want it to have.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a coordinate system set to Geographic (EPSG:4326). When I changed it back to a projected coordinate system the Advanced Digitizing tab re-activated.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled onto another method  `Vector => Geoprocessing tools`   then `Dissolve`.

Seems to do the trick, as an export renders as a single line.